# Count observations per date and per date & category

Tags: python, pandas, date

I need to explain one behavior of pandas.
Suppose this dataframe:

```py
index;day;id;value
0;2020-01-03;1;14
1;2020-01-03;1;2
2;2020-01-03;2;5
3;2020-01-05;1;7
4;2020-01-05;1;9
```

When I want to compute number of observation per day and id I can simple do:

```
df["frequency_per_id"] = df(["id", "day"])["id"].transform("count")
```

But when I want to compute the number of observations per day using the same formula:

```
df["frequency"] = df(["day"])["day"].transform("count")
```

I got an error `<ipython-input-16-3a624d98b3b5>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Can you explain me why? I do the same process? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It's a *warning*, not an error. I think the code will have done what you want it to do.

And it's a very common error, Googling "SettingWithCopyWarning" returns hundreds of articles and StackOverflow posts

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately the code is not doing anything..

Comment: Can you share some example outputs before and after applying ?